# Is it possible to have 2 analysis services linked to one Database engine? How do I install the second one?

Tags: installation, ssms, ssas, sql-server-2022

I am using SSMS 2022, and I have installed Database engine (developer server) for it. After that, using SQL SERVER Installation Center ( SETUP.EXE file in developer folder) I chose to add features to an existing instance of SQL Server 2022, and chose my server. I successfully added my first analysis server (which I want to use for creating Tabular model in SSAS). When I wanted to do the same procedure for the second analysis server (for multidimensional models), I couldn't checkmark the **Analysis Services** in **Feature Selection** section. The error I got was: To continue, select a feature to install. If all features are already selected, these features are installed. You cannot add additional features. I am not sure I fully understand if I can have several analysis servers connected to one Database engine.

Comment: *"I am using SSMS 2022"* There is no such thing. Do you mean *SQL Server 2022*? SSMS is a IDE-like application, and its latest version is SSMS 19, which came out of preview in 2023.

Comment: Yes. I meant 19, sorry. Sql server is 2022 and ssms is 19

Comment: You need to select the  "new instance of SQL Server" option and select Analysis services alone.